# java real diference of time from greenwich to my latitude and longitude

Tags: time

I want to know the real diference of time from greenwich to my latitude and longitude.
For example:
I am in La Coruna, Spain, and want to know the actual time difference between this position and the meridian of Greenwich.
In all the places that I've looked it indicates that the time difference is +1 hour, but I need to get the real difference of time, for example 0 hours, 45 minutes and 25 seconds
or, I would also know the distance in kilometers or meters.
You could tell me where I can learn to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: What data do you have? latitude/altitude could help...

Comment: Yes I have latitude and altitude.

Comment: sooooo, you know how many degree have the earth sphere and the diference between greenwich and the other side.... I'm spanish too. [Sabes en cuantos grados se divide el globo terraqueo y que en las antipodas con +12h ... regla de tres] 360º -> 24h

Comment: Thanks jabujavi.
I've done the math and have seen that each time slot of 1 hour corresponds to 15 degrees, so each grade 4 minutes. 1 degree corresponds to approximately 111.32 km.
But I am looking if anyone has a formula that tells me, from my longitude (-0.7823) the distance in kilometers and the time difference.
For example since this longitude, my time difference is 3 minutes and 7 seconds from Greenwich

Comment: The difference isn't in the km, it's in the degrees. Km are different at different latitudes.
At the equator are bigger than near to poles. Cause of this you only need the degrees.